# Installing eclipse IDE for Java EE developers on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, eclipse, jakarta-ee, terminal, installation

I'm new to the Linux method of program installation.  I have found instructions on how to install several different Eclipse versions such as JDK and CDK from the terminal but can't seem to find the package name for the Java EE version.

ex.  'sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt' installs the C++ version

I need the the option for Java EE, so what do I fill in the "option" below with?

'sudo apt-get install eclipse-option'

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get a few packages to get it working.

- eclipse
- eclipse-jdt
- eclipse-pde
- eclipse-platform
- eclipse-rcp

To install them:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-jdt eclipse-pde eclipse-platform eclipse-rcp
```

You can also find all packages that start with the name eclipse by using

```
apt-cache search eclipse | grep ^eclipse
```

Comment: So adding all the packages you listed is equivalent to the Java EE IDE?

Comment: These packages will get you set for java development. There are other packages which may seem useful like version control for git and merciurial.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint 17,Qiana, with MATE Desktop manager:

bring cursor to 'Menu'.
Left click on "Menu" in the panel.

Slide cursor half way down left side of menu,
Find and click on "Program Manager"

It will ask for your password.
Then, in the search box, you type "java ee eclipse" and it will display 8 different packages, which yo0u can again click on to read the descriptions below, and/or, check mark, to install.

Some have tools, some are servers, sure to please...

Answer (score 0):

The correct package for Java EE is

`eclipse-wtp`

Whereas "wtp" stands for web tool platform: http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/webtools

Imho you should not use apt to install eclipse, but download it directly from the eclipse website for the following reasons:

- At the time of writing the apt eclipse installation is last years release (Luna), though this years release (Mars) has already been around for half a year
- Eclipse has its own update tool
- There are no dependencies to be fulfilled in the apt package